# Is use of 'gotten' correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Has anybody gotten done pest control at their home?

Comment: Do you mean: "Has anybody gotten pest control done at their house?"

Comment: 'Get something done' (or 'have something done' with the same meaning) always has the direct object directly after the simplex verb. 'Gotten' / 'got' has been covered before on ELU.

Comment: No problem with *gotten*. Problem is with preceding  the *object* and deferring the *verb phrase*, as Peter Shor's comment says.

Comment: Source? Invented by you the poster or read somewhere online? The question needs detail.

Comment: Gotten is not usual in UK English, but more acceptable in the US, so where you are will be relevant. (Try searching here for "gotten".)

Comment: The past participle is truly the least of your worries here. Please edit this question to tell us what the basic infinitive and simple present tense constructions would be, one without any causatives or passives, let alone past participles. For example, you seem to be imagining that one "does pest control", or that one "has pest control done by others", or directs "others to do pest control". Those are shaky at best. What has your research shown? Are you familiar with our sister site for [ell.se]?

Comment: I *suspect* that OP's (completely unidiomatic) example is supposed to mean *Has anyone **had** pest control **done** at their home?* - still not very idiomatic to my ear, but the meaning seems clear enough there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we once had a huge wasp's nest in our back garden. The pest man from the council came. He got ready to go out and deal with it. He had his sleeves rolled up (it was a warm day). 'Aren't you worried about being stung?' asked my wife. 'No, love', he said patronisingly, 'I've been doing this for 20 years, and I've never been stung'. Out he went... two minutes... 'BUGGER!' In he rushed. Stung three times on his bare arms, but he finished the job.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Had you perhaps been *antagonising* the wasps? i always say if you're gonna mix it with a wasp, make sure you finish him off (or he might come gunning for you later, with several of his nest-mates! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wouldnt dare. I've had a healthy respect for wasps and bees ever since being stung on my belly aged two. Family legend has it that I made the loudest noise anyone present had ever heard.

Comment: If come for the wasp, you best not miss.